# How to detect a two finger swipe gesture on Android

Tags: android, swipe

I want to implement two finger swipe gesture in my android app. I have used the following code:

```
void handleTouch(MotionEvent m){
//Number of touches
int pointerCount = m.getPointerCount();
if(pointerCount == 2){
    int action = m.getActionMasked();
    int actionIndex = m.getActionIndex();
    String actionString;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testDiffText);
    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                   
            GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = (int) m.getX(1);
            actionString = "DOWN"+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
            tv.setText(actionString);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                 
            GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = 0;
            actionString = "UP"+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
            tv.setText(actionString);  
            break;  
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = (int) m.getX(1);
            int diff = GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X-GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X;
            actionString = "Diff "+diff+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
            tv.setText(actionString);                   
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = (int) m.getX(1);
            actionString = "DOWN"+" current "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X+" prev "+GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X;
            tv.setText(actionString);
            break;
        default:
            actionString = "";
    }

    pointerCount = 0;
}
else {
    GLOBAL_TOUCH_POSITION_X = 0;
    GLOBAL_TOUCH_CURRENT_POSITION_X = 0;
}
```

}

I'm getting same action performed in up or down swipe . it perform only Action_up task. can anyone please help me to implement both up to bottom swipe and bottom to up swipe.

Comment: The joy it brings me when I get to up-vote a closed question because it was EXACTLY what I was looking for, despite it being not "focused" - go figure.  The answer is trivially simple and yet it also helped, so another up-vote there. My campaign on SO continues...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int SWIPE = 1;
private int mode = NONE;
private float startY;
private float stopY;
// We will only detect a swipe if the difference is at least 100 pixels
// Change this value to your needs
private static final int TRESHOLD = 100;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            // This happens when you touch the screen with two fingers
            mode = SWIPE;
            // You can also use event.getY(1) or the average of the two
            startY = event.getY(0);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            // This happens when you release the second finger
            mode = NONE;
            if(Math.abs(startY - stopY) > TRESHOLD)
            {
                if(startY > stopY)
                {
                    // Swipe up
                }
                else
                {
                    //Swipe down
                }
            }
            this.mode = NONE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(mode == SWIPE)
            {
                stopY = event.getY(0);
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Is it work for on two finger swipe?

Comment: MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN means one finger.
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is two fingers.

Comment: Thanku so much @Inneke De Clippel.:)

Comment: Can u please help in left and right swipe also on two finger swipe.@Inneke De Clippel.

Comment: For left and right, you will have to save startX and stopX in the same way as startY and stopY. If (the difference between stopX and startX) is bigger than (the difference between stopY and startY), the swipe will be either left or right. So after that, if startX > stopX, the swipe was to the left.

Comment: a big big thanks to @Inneke De Clippel. Its working:)

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel could you please check [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135432/motion-event-single-and-double-finger-swipe) I'm trying to implement single and double finger Swipe at the same time